# How to customize highchart box plot box

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have to implement **candlestick stick graph**   through Highchart but since Highchart doesn't support candlestick graphs that's why I am trying to implement this through **box plot chart**  in Highchart. For this **I am doing this by setting the median to null**.

But the issue is that How can I reduce the width of box and also I have to remove horizontal line shows on low point and high point of box plot. Can any body suggest me to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `pointWidth` to make smaller width, but there is no option to remove vertical lines on how and low point, see: http://jsfiddle.net/mTdPh/

Comment: that's fine, can you plese tell me how to set x-axis as date and pass time values to data series instead of categories

Comment: Remove categories, and use or a) pointStart and pointInterval or b) timestamps (the same way as for Highstock).